# Image URL vs image download to display in web application using AWS S3

Tags: asp.net, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, asp.net-core-2.1

I have images stored in my AWS S3 and I would like to display it to a user. What is the most efficient way of doing that? Should I get the image url or download the image itself and display.

There are like 1000 images which need to be displayed.

Front-end - Angular
framework - .netcore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the permissions you have on your bucket. If it's public, then just link directly to the files in AWS. If it's private, then you'll have to download them with something that does have access (such as your app) and serve them to the user from there.